# I have two post types in the same query, how can I use CSS to select only one post type?

Tags: posts, css, query

I'm using OceanWP theme and Elementor at this site: https://mymythos.org/

Ritual, Relaxation, and Motivation are examples of the second post type. Most of the other posts are normal WP posts.

Comment: Friend of mine figured it out and it's painfully easy. article.posttype That's it. :|

Answer (score 0):

The [`post_class()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_class/) function can be used in the loop to automatically output some classes that you can target via CSS. Post types will have the class `type-[post-type]`.

How that might integrate with Elementor is unfortunately something you will need to ask via Elementor's support channels, as 3rd-party plugins and themes are off-topic here.